# Apache virtualhost : a specific host (subdomain) for all domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, virtualhost

I have a configuration accepting many domains on a production server (filtered by a proxy upstream). This Apache conf accepts *all domains* on 80 port and calls `/var/prod/` as `DocumentRoot`.

What I want is to redirect all *beta* subdomain only (`http://beta.domain1.ch`, `http://beta.domain2.ch`, `http://beta.domain3.ch`, ...) for every domains to `/var/beta/` DocumentRoot folder.

Is it possible with a mask in virtualhost tag like the following?

```
<VirtualHost beta.*:80>
```

Or do I need to put all my domains in `ServerAlias` ?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot        /var/beta/
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/beta/
    ServerAlias         beta.domain1.ch 
    ServerAlias         beta.domain2.ch
    ServerAlias         beta.domain3.ch
    ServerAlias         beta.domain4.ch
    ...
</virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot        /var/prod/
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/prod/
    ServerAlias         *.domain1.ch 
    ServerAlias         *.domain2.ch
    ServerAlias         *.domain3.ch
    ServerAlias         *.domain4.ch
    ...
</virtualhost>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: ServerAlias is used to define a second ServerName in the same VirtualHost, not what you want.

Comment: Actually it is. ServerAlias si for Name-based Virtual Hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As VirtualHost and serverNname doesn't accept wildcard, actually serverAlias does. This is working for me :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName          beta-server.main-domain.com
    ServerAlias         beta.*
    DocumentRoot        /var/beta/
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/beta/
</virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName          prod-server.main-domain.com
    ServerAlias         www.*
    DocumentRoot        /var/prod/
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/prod/
</virtualhost>
```

> Working on Apache 2.2, I need to test it on 2.4.